# Elastic Search incorrect Aggregation Counts

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have an index:

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "teacher_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "school_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "height": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "family_name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "studentID": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "performance_text": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "highlight": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "store": true,
                            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
                        },
                       "stemmed": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "snowball",
                            "fielddata": true
                       }
                    }
                },
                "_class": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": false,
                    "doc_values": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to search the performance_text and get the search results. I have performed aggregregations to be able to return the results grouped by school_id and teacher_id. Because each school contains multiple teachers and each teacher contains multiple students. I have done this because I want to display the search results for only 10 schools per page grouped further by teachers. Hence the aggregations. See the code below:

```
GET /my_index/_search?scroll=1m
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "performance_text.stemmed": "search_term"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "total_schools": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "school_id.keyword",
        "precision_threshold": 40000
      }
    },
    "total_students": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "studentID",
        "precision_threshold": 40000
      }
    },
    "schools": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "school_id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "teachers": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "teacher_id.keyword",
            "size": 1000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "students": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1000,
                "highlight": {
                  "fields": {
                    "performance_text.stemmed": {}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Each document in my elastic search index represents a student. But I also want the total hits for the search criteria. The elastic search limits the total hits to 10000 by default. So I use the scroll api. This gives me the total hits in the hits.total.value. This value of total hits doesn't match the total_students returned to me using cardinality. I have set the precision_threshold to its maximum value of 40000. Also, I want to retrieve the count of the unique schools(school_ids) which match the search criteria? I tried to use cardinality for it too, but it gives me incorrect results. I want the accurate count. How can I achieve this in the fastest way considering that the document collection in my es index is very large.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **track_total_hits: true**.
Here is the documentation:

[elasticsearch track total hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits)

> Generally the **total hit count can’t be computed accurately** without visiting all matches, which is costly for queries that match lots of documents. The track_total_hits parameter allows you to control how the total number of hits should be tracked. Given that it is often enough to have a lower bound of the number of hits, such as "there are at least 10000 hits", the default is set to 10,000. This means that requests will count the total hit accurately up to 10,000 hits. It is a good trade off to speed up searches if you don’t need the accurate number of hits after a certain threshold.
> ***When set to true the search response will always track the number of hits that match the query accurately.***

Comment: thanks for your answer. "track_total_hits": true works well to retrieve the total count, so that makes me rid of using the scroll_api. Additionally, I also need the count of the unique school_ids that match search. How can I achieve this?